# ruby rails 4 initialize and increment instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been tinkering with various ways to clean this up and I was wondering if it is more ideal to break this into small methods or way to accomplish this on a single line?

```
  def run_counters
    @num_attempts ||= 0
    @num_attempts += retry_attempt
    @all_attempts ||= 0
    @all_attempts += retry_limit
  end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review – your question has been migrated here. So that we may advise you properly, please add contextual information about what your code does, preferably a substantial part of the controller. Unlike Stack Overflow, which prefers short, abstract questions, Code Review needs full details. (See [ask].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either initialize the variables in your class's constructor (that's specifically what it's for!) or define  accessor methods to isolate the initialization logic for each variable:

```rb
# via constructor:

def initialize
  @num_attempts = 0
  @all_attempts = 0
end

def run_counters
  num_attempts += retry_attempt
  all_attempts += retry_limit
end
```

Or:

```
# via accessor methods:

def run_counters
  num_attempts += retry_attempt
  all_attempts += retry_limit
end

def num_attempts
  @num_attempts ||= 0
end

def all_attempts
  @all_attempts ||= 0
end
```

This also means you may safely access `num_attempts` and `all_attempts` from any other method, and not have to duplicate the initialization logic.

Comment: `run_counters` can be split into 2 different methods IMO.